# How can I save TTS nuance output in an audio file on android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, audio-recording

I use the api of nuance to text to speech (tts) on the platform of Android.
After each service request, service type vocalizer variable duty cycle and begins reading it right,
There is a function that runs when the reading begins, and a function that runs at the end of the reading.
I can not access the audio files themselves, to manage better in reading for my application.
I would be happy if someone tampered with it, and know how to do it.
thank you very much.